# Break while loop after x amount of time but continue for loop at the same level

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop, shopware

Currently I am working with some apis, in which I have to update or delete data.
To authenticate myself, I have to use some tokens, which are valid for like 10mins.

My tasks need more than 10minutes, so I can not finish my program properly.

My solution for this problem would be to track the time and after 9mins, I want to request the new token and keep going exactly where I left off in my for loop.

```py
import time

end_time = time.time() + 60*9
while time.time() < end_time:
    for repetition in range(0, 4):
        sw_patcher_ghp = Shopware()
        bearer_token_ghp = sw_patcher_ghp.get_access_token()
        continue
        ##compare both files if skus are matching, grab the data which is needed for patching ruleIds
        for i in range(0, len(all_json)):
            for ii in range(0, len(all_csv)):
                if all_json[i][0] == all_csv[ii][0]:
                    print(sw_patcher_ghp.patch_ruleid(bearer_token_ghp, all_json[i][1], all_csv[ii][1], true_boolean), 'GHP', all_json[i][1])
```

Now the big problem is:
How can I request the new token, but I also have to be able to continue the for loop at the point I have left

E.g when I left at i = 500, I want to start after I have received the new tokens at 501

Comment: Why not just check for elapsed time before each call to `patch_ruleid()` and get a new `bearer_token_ghp` if needed?

Comment: you can update token in your nested loop

Comment: @quamrana I think I know what you wants to point out, but then I am at the very same point or? Maybe I have misunderstood you

Comment: @FilipMłynarski yes I know, but I dont want to update the tokens each loop I completed, because I am poor and so is the webserver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `while` loop really. Just request for a new token within your innermost loop if 9 minutes have passed and update `end_time`:

```
for repetition in range(0, 4):
    sw_patcher_ghp = Shopware()
    bearer_token_ghp = sw_patcher_ghp.get_access_token()
    
    for i in range(0, len(all_json)):
        for ii in range(0, len(all_csv)):
            if all_json[i][0] == all_csv[ii][0]:
                if end_time >= time.time():
                    #enter code here get new token
                    end_time = time.time()+60*9
                else:
                    print(sw_patcher_ghp.patch_ruleid(bearer_token_ghp, all_json[i][1], all_csv[ii][1], true_boolean), 'GHP', all_json[i][1])
```

Comment: I just played around with while loops, I never had to use before.. Maybe I was so focused of using the while loop that I did not even think about other ways to achieve this..

Comment: after playing a bit around and changing ```if end_time >= time.time()``` to ```if time_now - start_time >= 480(value for seconds), it worked :)
your suggestion helped somehow with the outsource of my class objects, thanks lawd! :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I think that you mean that just getting a new token can happen at any time, but you want to try every 9 minutes:

```py
import time

end_time = time.time() - 1  # force end_time to be invalid at the start
for repetition in range(0, 4):
    ##compare both files if skus are matching, grab the data which is needed for patching ruleIds
    for i in range(0, len(all_json)):
        for ii in range(0, len(all_csv)):
            if all_json[i][0] == all_csv[ii][0]:
                if time.time() > end_time:
                    end_time = time.time() + 60*9
                    sw_patcher_ghp = Shopware()
                    bearer_token_ghp = sw_patcher_ghp.get_access_token()

                print(sw_patcher_ghp.patch_ruleid(bearer_token_ghp, all_json[i][1], all_csv[ii][1], true_boolean), 'GHP', all_json[i][1])
```

Comment: yes exactly! Its not very important if I get the new token after 6mins or something like that. I just want to be sure, that I dont get too close to 10mins but also I dont want to request every second a new token. Thanks for your suggestion, I will hook on right now

Comment: this suggestion does not work for me :/. The program finishes after couple of seconds

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if time.time() > end_time`?

Comment: Oops. I guess so. I'll update. That's my most frequent error: Getting a logical statement the inverse of what I meant.